# Returning from the Conditional (or Ternary) Operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Can someone please give me a reason as to why I can't return expressions while using the Ternary operator?

```
while( root != nullptr )
{
    if( current->data > v ) {
        ( current->left == nullptr ) ? return false : current = current->left;
    } else if( current->data < v ) {
        current->right == nullptr ? return false : current = current->right;
    } else if( current->data == v ) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Why will I get errors when I try and return false? I understand I can do this:

```
return ( ( 0 == 1 ) ? 0 : 1 );
```

But what is the problem with the compiler when just trying to return from one of the expressions?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the `return` statement does not have a defined value (it's not an expression), while each of the right two elements of the ternary operator is supposed to have a value. There's also a bug in your code: the loop should be testing that `current` is not `nullptr`; `root` doesn't change through the loop, so the loop would never exit normally.

Just rewrite it as nested `if` statements:

```
current = root;
while( current != nullptr )
{
    if( current->data > v ) {
        if( current->left == nullptr ) return false;
        current = current->left;
    } else if( current->data < v ) {
        if( current->right == nullptr) return false;
        current = current->right;
    } else if( current->data == v ) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

In fact, though, for this particular logic, you don't need the inner `return` statements at all:

```
current = root;
while( current != nullptr )
{
    if( current->data > v ) {
        current = current->left;
    } else if( current->data < v ) {
        current = current->right;
    } else if( current->data == v ) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

However, if you're enamored of the ternary operator and simply must use it, you can:

```
current = root;
while( current != nullptr )
{
    if( current->data == v ) {
        return true;
    }
    current = (current->data > v) ? current->left : current->right;
}
return false;
```

Comment: @CaseyGardiner - I expanded on my answer a bit since you saw it; you might want to read it again and see if it's right.

Comment: The second part is not correct. I didn't debug it in detail but I the program broke while trying to find data in the tree. Once I pasted what you had with the return falses it worked fine. Thanks again

Comment: @CaseyGardiner - Did you change the loop condition to test `current` instead of `root`?

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator creates a new expression from multiple sub-expressions. A `return` statement is not an expression.